# Oblic text as tile XAML

Tags: xaml, text, tile

I would like to display a text over other component in XAML. This text is used to display "DEMO VERSION" over all the elements on my application.
How can I display oblic text in tile mode?

Like this image:
[image]

The container size can change, I want the text to repeat to fill the container.
Any idea?

Comment: WPF or SL? You can accomplish this with a DrawingBrush with TileMode in WPF, but SL requires a bit more finesse.

Comment: Well, I just pointed you in a direction, but if it answered it then that's all the better. Cheers

Comment: I found a similar way to do this, using textBlock and VisualBrush:
<VisualBrush Viewport="0,0,380,140" ViewportUnits="Absolute" TileMode="Tile">
 <VisualBrush.Visual>
  <StackPanel Background="Transparent">
   <TextBlock FontSize="10pt" Margin="10" Text="Version Demo"/>
  </StackPanel>
 </VisualBrush.Visual>
 <VisualBrush.Transform>
  <RotateTransform Angle="-45" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" />
 </VisualBrush.Transform>
</VisualBrush>